# The breakdown of the solution to the ODE $y' = \sqrt{4-2y}$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose $y=y(x)$ be a real valued function such that 
$$
y(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{4-2y(t)} dt.
$$
By differentiating both side with respect to $x$, we get the ODE
$$
y' = \sqrt{4-2y}, \quad y(0)=0.
$$
This is a separable equation which has 
$$
y_1(x) = -\frac 12 (2-x)^2 + 2
$$
as the solution. By inspection,
$$\begin{align}
y_1'(x) &=2-x, \\
\sqrt{4-2y_1(x)} &= |2-x|
\end{align}$$
so this solution works for $x\le 2$.

> Is it possible to continue to solution pass $x=2$? I know one trivial answer which is
>   $$
> y(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac 12 (2-x)^2 + 2 &; x\le 2 \\
> 2 &; x>2.
> \end{cases}
> $$

Using the notation from the Picard-Lindelof theorem, we have 
$$
y' = f(y)
$$
where $f(y) = \sqrt{4-2y}$ so $f$ is not Lipschitz at $y=2$ so the breakdown at $x=2$ (which causes $y(2)=2$) is to be expected. However, I don't know much about ODE apart from the general local existence result so I'd be very glad if someone could tell me if there is any other possible extension of the solution pass $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
y'(x) &= \sqrt{4-2y(x)}\\
y'(x) &= \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-y(x)}\\
\dfrac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{2-y(x)}} &= \sqrt{2}\\
\int\dfrac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{2-y(x)}} dx&= \int\sqrt{2}dx\\
-2\sqrt{-y(x)+2}&=\sqrt{2}x+K_1\\
y(x)&=-\dfrac{1}{4}(\sqrt{2}x+K_1)^2-2\\
\end{align}
$$
For, $y(0)=0$: 
$$K_1=\{-2;2\}.$$
Therefore,

$$
y(x) = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{2}x(x-4), & \mbox{if } K_1 = -2 \mbox{, } x\geq 2 \\ 
-\dfrac{1}{2}x(x+4), & \mbox{if } K_1 = 2 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: At certain point you have $-2\sqrt{-y(x)+2}=\sqrt{2}x+K_1$ before squaring both sides. Doesn't this imply that $K_1=-2\sqrt 2$ is the only possibility?

Comment: But this constant is not for all the solution of $y(x)$, it constraints $y(x)\leq2$. You determine the constant after you define the general form of $y(x)$ like I did.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. $y\le 2$ is already given from the fact that $\sqrt{4-2y}$ must be defined.

Comment: You solutions also have negative slope on your domain but that's impossible since $y' = \sqrt{4-2y} \ge 0$.

Comment: Good, points. However, now that I briefly checked, I can say that: $y(x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}x(x+4)$ verifies the ODE. Also, I couldn't find where and what I did wrong (it is possible). Hope someone comes with a better solution, and I will delete mine then. tried to help you out. :(